# Connections vs DataSources

Tags: java, jdbc

I am reading about `Connection`s vs `DataSource`s in Java and I have some questions. Is a `DataSource` really just a manager and an abstraction of a `Connection` (or multiple connections)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html):

> A factory for connections to the physical data source that this DataSource object represents. An alternative to the DriverManager facility, a DataSource object is the preferred means of getting a connection.

Actually, a `DataSource` is a provider of `Connection`s and it has a variety of implementations which operate in different manners. Such as:

> 1. Basic implementation -- produces a standard Connection object
> 2. Connection pooling implementation -- produces a Connection object that will automatically participate in connection pooling. This
>      implementation works with a middle-tier connection pooling manager.
> 3. Distributed transaction implementation -- produces a Connection object that may be used for distributed transactions and almost always
>      participates in connection pooling. This implementation works with a
>      middle-tier transaction manager and almost always with a connection
>      pooling manager.

Answer (score 5):

`Connection` is the connection :) `DataSource` is a manager of connections (pool of connections).

Comment: I am not sure if this answer is 100% accurate and correct.

Answer (score -1):

Data source is the source of your data, the connection is the driver.

Answer (score -1):

DataSource is ill concept in its existing form as if it was meant to abstract interactions it should not return some SQL connection to interact with in the first place. Also it is overkill and XA is fantasy concept that some paid dearly for lack of reliable implementation in the world (I mean all enterprise commercial implementers simply fail and expose business... someone got hurt because of it in finance, but I will not mention names). In general, regardless if Sun or Oracle recommends it, it results in over-engineering and some technical dirt in code (dealing with contexts, extra steps to get to data, some external configurations... and in the end it is still specific to vendor implementations anyway). Some developed coroporate solutions that deal with pooling, connection recovery e.t.c much better based on plain connections and DriverManager than DataSource implemtations provided by enterprise DBMS vendors.

For the record I worked with both and I base it on facts encountered in different places. And if you doubt it then ask why you can see plain JDBC URL in Hibernate configuration all over the place in businesses. Many simply dump the heavyweigtt idea of J2EE and go lightweight... also using plain connections based on DriverManager.

You want to get your career on line then go ahead with XA DataSources and recovery of failed transactions where poor XA implemetation failed badly.